# How to split an array index

Tags: javascript

how to split an array index i.e.. sample code

```
var parts = currentVal.split(" ");
var datePart = parts.splice(0,1);
alert("Date: " + datePart );
var timePart = parts.join(' ');
```

here i am validating the date time regular expression. var datePart is an  array index, now i want to split datepart ....

```
var parts1 = datePart.split('/');
parts1.date = parseInt(parts1[0]);
parts1.month = parseInt(parts1[1]);
parts1.year = parseInt(parts1[2]);
```

but it is showing uncaught type error, their is no method split(); Can any one help me how do i separate date, month, year.

Comment: What is currentVal? Show the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to just check whether a string represents a valid date or not, I would personally recommend the magical `Date` object that javascript natively supports.  Through some sort of wizardry it can read the date in almost any format you throw at it, and if it is an invalid date it will evaluate to the string `Invalid Date`.

So to check if `currentVal` is a valid date, do:

```
if (new Date(currentVal) == 'Invalid Date') {
    ... // The date is invalid
} else {
    ... // The date is valid
}
```

On the other hand, if you need to use a specific regex to validate the date, you could either do something like

```
var parts = currentVal.split(' ');
var dateParts = parts[0].split('/');
var timePart = parts[1]; // Maybe you want to split this as well?
```

And this would leave dateParts as an array containing the month, day and year.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the function explode().
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

Actually function splice returns an array of removed elements, so to solve you problem you just need to apply split on the first element of datePart array:

```
var parts1 = datePart[0].split("/");
```